# Mongo aggregation for a DbRef field with mongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

Assume I have two mongo collections as follows.

```
Collection A
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0"),
    "level" : "super"
    "dataReference" : Object
        B : DbRef(B, 5b618a570550de0021aaa2ef, undefined)
}

Collection B
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b618a570550de0021aaa2ef"),  
    "role" : "admin"
}
```

What I need is retrieve the records from Collection A, which records have "level" field's value as "super" and its related Collection B record's "role" value as "admin".

For this, I am trying to use aggregation and java mongoTemplate.

Following is the code that I tried but it returns 0 records.

```
final TypedAggregation<A> typedAggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(A.class,
                Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("level").equals(level)),
                Aggregation.lookup("B", "_id", "dataReference.B.$id", "Basb"),
                Aggregation.match(new Criteria().andOperator(
                        Criteria.where("B.role").regex("admin")
                )));

        final AggregationResults<Map> A = mongoTemplate.aggregate(typedAggregation, "A", Map.class);
```

Please note that I am new to Mongo aggregation.

Comment: You have wrong syntax. Change `Criteria.where("level").equals(level)` to `Criteria.where("level").is(level)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quiet ugly solution:

### MongoTemplate

You cannot use `TypedAggregation` because we need to transform `A` collection to be able join with `B` collection

```
Aggregation typedAggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("level").is("super")),
    new AggregationOperation() {
        @Override
        public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
            return Document.parse("{\"$addFields\":{\"dataReference\":{\"$reduce\":{\"input\":{\"$objectToArray\":\"$dataReference\"},\"initialValue\":null,\"in\":{\"$cond\":[{\"$eq\":[{\"$type\":\"$$this.v\"},\"objectId\"]},\"$$this.v\",\"$$value\"]}}}}}");
        }
    },
    Aggregation.lookup("B", "dataReference", "_id", "B"),
    Aggregation.match(new Criteria().andOperator(
             Criteria.where("B.role").regex("admin")
        )
    )
);

final AggregationResults<Document> A = mongoTemplate.aggregate(typedAggregation, "A", Document.class);
```

### MongoDB Aggregation

```
db.A.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "level": "super"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "B": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$objectToArray": "$dataReference"
          },
          "initialValue": null,
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  {
                    "$type": "$$this.v"
                  },
                  "objectId"
                ]
              },
              "$$this.v",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "B",
      "localField": "B",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "B"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "B.role": {
            "$regex": "admin",
            "$options": ""
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/InHBIFburDz)

Comment: How to cast the result set to class A

Comment: @UdaraSeneviratne change `Document.class` to `A.class`

Comment: Actually I am getting "No converter found capable of converting from type [org.bson.types.ObjectId] to type [com.DataReference]"

Comment: I had to update this little bit. Please refer to https://mongoplayground.net/p/yYYlBzmAYmW

Comment: @UdaraSeneviratne take a look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-index-annotations-converter#converters)